# python multiprocessing behaviour

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I've noticed strange behaviour when running some python code that made use of the multiprocessing library.  This is all under Windows and likely a Windows thing, but maybe someone could explain what's happening.

If I create a simple python script and create a pool like so:

```
import multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
print "made a pool"

while True:
    pass
```

when I run the script I see "made a pool" printed 8 times, which would be the default number of processes created by `Pool()` as I have 8 cores on my machine.

When I change the script to be like so:

```
import multiprocessing

def run():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    print "made a pool"

    while True:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I see "made a pool" printed once - which is what I would have expected in both cases.

I guess I would normally run any code using the multiprocessing library from a function, but got caught out by this while playing with some code in a single python file.  Anyone know why it happens?

Comment: Did you read the "note" at the top of the multiprocessing documentation page, and the [section of the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) to which it links?

Comment: Ah thanks, missed that. It does say you shouldn't create a pool in the main module under Windows.